# Exporting multiple csv files with dynamic naming

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I created about 200 csv files in Python and now need to download them all.

I created the files from a single file using:

```
g = df.groupby("col")
for n,g in df.groupby('col'):
    g.to_csv(n+'stars'+'.csv')
```

When I try to use this same statement to export to my machine I get a syntax error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
g = df.groupby("col")
for n,g in df.groupby('col'):
    g.to_csv('C:\Users\egagne\Downloads\'n+'stars'+'.csv'')
```

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-27-43a5bfe55259>", line 3
    g.to_csv('C:\Users\egagne\Downloads\'n+'stars'+'.csv'')
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm in Jupyter lab, so I can download each file individually but I really don't want to have to do that.

Comment: Try something along the lines of `g.to_csv('C:\Users\egagne\Downloads\'+str(n)+'stars.csv')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're possibly mixing up integers and strings, and the use of backslash in literals is dangerous anyway. Consider using the following

```
import os
```

inside the loop

```
    f_name = os.path.join('C:', 'users', ' egagne', 'Downloads', str(n), 'stars.csv')
    g.to_csv(f_name)
```

with [`os.path.join`](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=python+os+path+join&oq=python+os+path+join&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2804j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) taking care of the backslashes for you.

Answer (score 1):

`g.to_csv('C:\Users\egagne\Downloads\'n+'stars'+'.csv'')`
needs to be
`g.to_csv('C:\\Users\\egagne\\Downloads\\'+n+'stars.csv')`.

There were two things wrong -- the backslash is an escape character so if you put a `'` after it, it will be treated as part of your string instead of a closing quote as you intended it. Using `\\` instead of a single `\` escapes the escape character so that you can include a backslash in your string.

Also, you did not pair your quotes correctly. `n` is a variable name but from the syntax highlighting in your question it is clear that it is part of the string. Similarly you can see that `stars` and `.csv` are not highlighted as part of a string, and the closing `''` should be a red flag that something has gone wrong.

Edit: I addressed what is causing the problem but Ami Tavory's answer is the right one -- though you know this is going to run on windows it is a better practice to use `os.path.join()` with directory names instead of writing out a path in a string. `str(n)` is also the right way to go if you are at all unsure about the type of n.